# Why does create-react-app fail to compile after switching branch in local development docker?

Tags: git, docker, docker-compose, create-react-app

I created a `docker-compose.yml` to configure local development docker environment. Everything seems to work fine except when I switch branch with `git`, `create-react-app` suddenly fails to recompile. File changes continue to be detected, and hot module reloading is attempted, but I almost always end up with the `Failed to compile` or `Error: invalid hook call` error in `react-error-overlay`. The only way I can recover from this is running `docker-compose restart <service name>`.

[image: Failed to compile]

[image: Invalid hook call]

Why does `create-react-app` fail to compile in the local development docker after a branch change? How do I go about debugging what is going on?

Note running `docker-compose restart <service name>` is not desirable because the build process takes 2 minutes, and I don't want to wait 2 minutes every time after I change branch.